# Rendering null in react element prevents me from using css's :empty selector

Tags: reactjs

To better explain my question, I'll use an example:

Let's say I have two react elements, which contain one another. Lets call the container `Box`, and the child `Stuff`. `Box` just renders a `div` with `className="box"` which surrounds the children it is given. `Stuff` most of the time renders something, but its `render` function can return `null` when it decides there's nothing to render.

Here's the twist: if `<Box>` is empty, I don't want to show it at all. So I decided to use css3 selectors, and write something like

```
.box:empty {
    display: none;
}
```

... which *should* work, except react renders a `<noscript>` tag, which prevents the browser from treating the parent `.box` element as empty...

Is there an elegant way around this? I'd like to keep the logic of determining emptiness inside of `Stuff`, and have `Box` just "look" at its contents and decide whether it wants to show anything or not.

**UPDATE**

This fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/67543/ has an example of what I'm trying to do. Strangely, in that fiddle, it *works*, and react doesn't render `<noscript>` tags... why does it render `<noscript>`s in my code? In what cases does react choose to render `<noscript>`s?

Comment: Why not do an empty check on the react side?

Comment: How can I check emptiness in react?

Comment: You'd have to ask the Stuff Component whether it has any children (via the props property?) and based on the state of Stuff show the Box or not. Might want to share some code there

Comment: But "Stuff" doesn't have any react children, only Box does.
Also, I'd prefer to avoid re-renders if possible.

Comment: Can you upload the code of those two components?

Comment: Not really, but I can show the gist of things:

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/67543/

Weirdly enough, in that fiddle, it works, and react doesn't render `<noscript>` tags... why does it render `<noscript>`s in my code? In what cases does react choose to render `<noscript>`s?

Comment: If I recall correctly rendering noscript is the old behaviour. I assume you're using an older version of React and the pen works because it uses a more recent version.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so too. However both `import version from 'react/lib/ReactVersion'` and `import version from 'react-dom/lib/ReactVersion'`  return `15.4.2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem!

I was using an old version of `react-css-modules` (3.7.7). Upgrading to 4.1.0 fixed it.

Looks like this was a relatively recent fix, too:
https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules/commit/a9c8de252d5464037090e155c431abfe9f671531

Comment: If you found an answer, mark it as such; it would be clearer to anyone viewing this page